# Script no entra en condicional cuando debería

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Tengo una duda con el siguiente script: no me devuelve la igualdad. Esperaría ver un mensaje “face 2” en la consola pero no entra en el `if`. A continuación dejo el script para menos palabras:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").on("click", function cambiar(){
    if($(this).html()=="on"){
      console.log("face 2");
      //la consola no me devuelve face 2 
    }
  })
});
```

```html
<button>
  on
</button>
```

Comment: Hola jofret, por favor completa el [tour] para aprender más sobre Stack Overflow en español y ver cómo funciona el sitio en general (además ganarás una nueva medalla con ello). También deberías leer [ask] y cómo crear un [mcve] y seguir los consejos que encontrarás allí. Es importante que las preguntas tengan un título descriptivo, estén bien etiquetadas y tengan un planteamiento claro para que sean de ayuda a otros usuarios.

Comment: Además, el problema de la pregunta no se corresponde con el problema real ([puesto en los comentarios](/questions/187054/script-no-entra-en-condicional-cuando-debería#comment350269_187057)) ni con la [respuesta aceptada](/a/187057/250). Lee  [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?](/help/someone-answers) y [answer] para aprender más sobre cómo actuar cuando algún usuario responde o si encontraste la respuesta a tu propia pregunta (en SO se permite y se anima a responder a tus propias publicaciones).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te saludo y te comento lo siguiente tu código ya lo probé y es funcional, seguramente te hacía falta la invocación a la librería de JQuery justo antes de tu script personalizado; te dejo este ejemplo totalmente funcional

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <button>on</button>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js"></script>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
   $("button").on("click", function cambiar(){
    if($(this).text()=="on"){
    console.log("face 2");
    }
   })
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Una recomendación mas

> Te recomiendo que en vez de `html()` uses el método `.text()` que
>   ayuda a obtener una cadena de texto del nodo del DOM que estes
>   consultando; te dejo la fuente oficial de la documentación de JQuery
>   sobre lo que te menciono

http://api.jquery.com/text/

Comment: Gracias! lo que pasaba con el código era que tenía espacio entre las etiquetas <button>   on   </button>.Te dejo mi código final. Gracias de antemano por cualquier comentaro adicional : $(document).ready(function(){
   $("button").on("click", function(e){
    event.preventDefault();
    if($(this).text()=="inglés"){
    $(this).text("español")
    $(".textoespanol").css({"display":"none"});
    $(".textoIngles").fadeIn( 1000 );
    } else { 
     $(this).text("inglés");
     $(".textoIngles").css({"display":"none"});
     $(".textoespanol").fadeIn(1000);
     }
   }) 
    })